# dynamic select with relation to other selection

Tags: angular-formly

I have two methods to get data from remote service.

Api.types() returns me [{name:'vegetable', id:0}, {name:'fruit', id:1}]. Based on that returns and if i change selected type it should update **variety** field data with data about fruits/vegetables. What's wrong at that code?

```
controller('MainCtrl', ['$log', 'Api', function($log, Api) {
  this.formFields = [
    {
       key: "type",
       type: "select",
       templateOptions: {
         label: "Types",
         valueProp: "id",
         labelProp: "name",
         options:[],
       },
       expressionProperties: {
         'templateOptions.options': function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
            Api.types()
              .then(function(ok) { scope.to.options=ok;}, function(error){});
         }
       },
    },
    {
       key: "variety",
       type: "select",
       templateOptions: {
         label: "variety",
         valueProp: "id",
         labelProp: "name",
         options:[],
       },
       expressionProperties: {
         'templateOptions.options': function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
            Api.variety(scope.model.type)
             .then(function(ok) { scope.to.options=ok;}, function(error){});
         }
       },
    }
  ];

});
```

Comment: Instead of doing `Api.types().then(function(ok) { scope.to.options=ok;}, function(error){});` try simply `return Api.types()`

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything.

```
expressionProperties: {
         'templateOptions.options': function($viewValue, $modelValue, scope) {
           $scope.to.options=[]; //reset to avoid having issues when selecting
           return Api.variety(scope.model.type)
             .then(function(ok) { 
                  scope.to.options=ok;
                  return $scope.to.options;
             }, function(error){});

         }
       },
```